# How to get URL from Chrome share text

Tags: android, android-intent

I am working project that require to get the URL when user share a selected text from the Chrome browser.

[image]

I was able to get the text by using `ACTION_PROCESS_TEXT` but how do I get the URL? so that I know where the text copied from.

Is it even possible?

Answer (score 1):

> how do I get the URL?

You don't. If the user chooses "Share" in Chrome, and you have an activity with an `<intent-filter>` for `ACTION_SEND` and `text/plain`, your app should appear in the share sheet and, if the user chooses your app, your activity can get the text. However, that is a separate user action than the one for sharing text with your app with `ACTION_PROCESS_TEXT`.